# Echo results not showing

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables in one db, and one is foreign keyed to the other.  My problem is that I'm trying to call up information stored in one table based on the user name which links the 2 tables stored in the other.  Here is my php, mind you I'm pretty fresh on the databasing and php, so cut some slack. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$loaduser= $_SESSION['username'];
$loaduser_conn= @mysql_connect("DB_NAME","DB_USER","DB_PASS");

mysql_select_db("user_register") or die ("Couldn't find user database.");

$gal_result= mysql_query("SELECT shoot_name FROM images WHERE username='$loaduser'") or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gal_result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    foreach($results['shoot_name'] as $result)
    {
        echo $result['shoot_name'], '<br>';

        if(mysql_num_rows($gal_result) !=1) {
            die("No galleries found for this user.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You check for results *after you fetch and loop through your results. Does that seem right? 2. You are using obsolete code

Comment: A lot of problems here. I suggest going back to the drawing board and starting over.

Comment: exactly where does `$results` come from? You 99.999999% certainly don't have error_reporting/display_errors enabled, or you'd get told about your undefined variables, foreach failures.

Comment: try putting `ini_set('display_errors',1);` directly after `<?php` in your file to see errors, warnings, etc..

Comment: I appreciate the feedback guys,  Ill check the errors.

Comment: Also, you might want to stop using the `mysql_` library while you're just starting out (it is deprecated completely out of the latest php); and instead use `mysqli` or `pdo` libraries (and, most importantly, the parameterized queries they offer).

Comment: well, you're using comas instead of dots when concatenate strings

Comment: I appreciate all the info.  Ive been researching for days and have found nothing that has helped.  Its been suggested that I start this script from scratch, any idea where I could get a better start at?

Comment: I inserted ini_set('display_errors',1) ; and received no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can google "PHP PDO tutorial" and find many resources. Here's one that is very clear and well written: like: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Here's a better example:

```
<?php

$loaduser = $_SESSION['username'];

// use PDO, not the deprecated mysql extension
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_register";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, "DB_USER", "DB_PASS");

// set exception errmode, so code dies automatically if there's an error
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// use a parameterized query instead of concatenating variables into SQL 
$sql = "SELECT shoot_name FROM images WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$loaduser]);

// fetch all into an array of results
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// check the count of the results with < 1 instead of != 1
// in case it's 2 or more
if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1) {
    die("No galleries found for this user.");
}

// loop through results
foreach($results as $row) {
    // use dot for string concatenation instead of comma. 
    echo $row["shoot_name"] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. $results has to be fetched before tryin to get its contents.
2. While trying to get its contents you were fetching $row instead of $results
3. You are using mysql, mysql has been deprecated try using mysqli or PDO in the future.

Try this anyway.

```
<?php
$loaduser= $_SESSION['username'];

$loaduser_conn= @mysql_connect("DB_NAME","DB_USER","DB_PASS");
mysql_select_db("user_register") or die ("Couldn't find user database.");

$gal_result= mysql_query("SELECT shoot_name FROM images WHERE username='$loaduser'") or die (mysql_error());

$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($gal_result,MYSQL_ASSOC)

while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($gal_result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  foreach($results['shoot_name'] as $result) {

  echo $result['shoot_name'], '<br>';

  if(mysql_num_rows($gal_result) !=1){
    die("No galleries found for this user.");
  }

  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting to this untested snippet (in case you want to keep using deprecated code ;))

```
$loaduser= $_SESSION['username'];
$loaduser_conn= @mysql_connect("DB_NAME","DB_USER","DB_PASS");
mysql_select_db("user_register") or die ("Couldn't find user database.");
$gal_result= mysql_query("SELECT shoot_name FROM images WHERE username='$loaduser'") or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($gal_result)==0){ // returns number of rows so if 0 there are no rows
    die("No galleries found for this user.");
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($gal_result)) { // "while" is already your loop. No need for the foreach within.
    echo $row['shoot_name'], '<br>';
}
```

If you want to select from multiple tables with some reference try this query:

```
$gal_result= mysql_query("SELECT shoot_name FROM images AS a LEFT JOIN your_other_table AS b ON a.username = b.username WHERE a.username='$loaduser'") or die (mysql_error());
```

Like anyone i would advise you on using more up to date code.
See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php